# how do you return error level ($?) after its been piped to while?

Tags: bash, while-loop, errorlevel

in bash i am trying to make a script that goes:

```
echo hi | while read line; do echo $line; done
```

&

```
echo $?
```

would return 0

---

lets say the first script messed up somehow:

```
ech hi | while read line; do echo $line; done
```

&

```
echo $?
```

would still return 0

How does one go about returning that error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Bash internal variable `$PIPESTATUS` does this. It is an array containing the exit status(es) of the commands in the last executed pipe. The first command in the pipe is `$PIPESTATUS[0]`, etc:

```
$ ech hi | while read line; do echo $line; done
-bash: ech: command not found
$ echo ${PIPESTATUS[0]} ${PIPESTATUS[1]}
127 0

$ echo hi | while read line; do ech $line; done
-bash: ech: command not found
$ echo ${PIPESTATUS[0]} ${PIPESTATUS[1]}
0 127

$ echo hi | while read line; do echo $line; done
hi
$ echo ${PIPESTATUS[0]} ${PIPESTATUS[1]}
0 0
```

Comment: Thanks dude. I mean that.

Comment: Updated with more info/accuracy. If this is enough, consider accepting my answer. :)